# Building a centralized configuration repository

Tags: database, unix, configuration, interface, ldap

I'm trying to develop an open source application to be sort like a centralized configuration management for all Unix platform like for example (changing root password, SSH configuration, DNS settings, /etc/hosts management.... and others).

I need your feedback for what do you recommend to use as the interface for all the configuration (list of scripts will be running in the Unix Servers as a clients to read the configuration and apply it in each system "Client===>to===>Server mode"

Should I use LDAP to host the configurations and any Unix OS can talk to the LDAP to get the configuration

or Should I just save the configuration in Database (e.g. MySQL) and build a web interface to read the database and print the configuration to the client ?

or you have any other idea?

Comment: Did you ever develop or find your solution? Chris Read came out with ESCAPE a couple of years ago, but it's stagnated. I'm looking to build something similar, as it's a gaping hole in the landscape.

Answer (score 3):

You might look into something like [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home) or [Puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) instead. Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: I'm looking to do something with different features, my proble with puppet as that you have to do all configuration in text and people need to learn (your admins). I want to do something like AD for Linux/Unix

Comment: That could be done as a (very useful) front-end to puppet/chef. Good luck with your project btw, it sounds interesting.

Comment: Puppet can use a database for the config variables, and Cfengine can use LDAP as the source for variables.  Once you've defined your configuration, the other admins can just change parameters in the referenced database.

Answer (score 2):

[Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) can download a file from a URL and write that file to standard output. For example, executing `curl -sS http://someHost/file.cfg` will download "file.cfg" from the specified web server. The "-sS" options instruct Curl to print error messages but not any any progress diagnostics. By the way, Curl supports many protocols including HTTP, FTP and LDAP, so you have flexibility in the technology you want to use to host your centralised configuration repository (CCR).

You could use curl to retrieve a configuration file from the CCR, store the result in a local file and then parse that local file.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Blueprint from DevStructure. It sounds like something along the lines of what you're trying to do. Basically it reverse engineers servers and detects everything that has changed from the install state. Open-source too.

https://github.com/devstructure/blueprint (Blueprint @ Github)

Answer (score 1):

We are also about to launch ConfigChief which is a central configuration repository that would do what you want: central point to store configuration (with all features like versioning, audit, ACL, inheritence, etc).

Once you have that, combined with change notification, you can just run a curl as Ciaran McHale says against the CCR and get your parsed configuration file back. This would eliminate the need for writing scripts to generate config files from the outside.

If you are interested, you can signup for a beta at http://woot.configchief.com

**DISCLAIMER**: I guess it is obvious from the first word!

Comment: The link is not available any more